# How do I output UTF8 Lithuanian characters using php?

Tags: php, utf-8

I'm trying to decode this, but it's not working.

```
<?php
  ini_set('default_charset','utf-8');
  header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  echo utf8_decode("Ä…ÄÄ™Ä—Ä¯Å¡Å³Å«Å¾");
?>
```

This should display "ąčęėįšųūž" but prints it "�?č�?�?įšųūž". How can I fix it? Please help me set UTF-8 file charset, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The string which you are echoing might partially be UTF-8 but some of the characters are wrong. This is the correct string:

```
ÄÄÄÄÄ¯Å¡Å³Å«Å¾
```

utf8_decode converts a string encoded in UTF8 to ISO 8859-1. I guess that's not really what you need.

---

Check your source for its encoding and then choose which function you need to convert it to utf8.